# No output in Linux Keyboard Logger running in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I'm trying to run LKL (Linux Keyboard Logger) in a Ubuntu 9.04 VirtualBox VM 
(VirtualBox 2.2.2 running on a XP host). The package installs
fine, but when I try to run it

```
lkl -l -k /usr/share/lkl/keymaps/us_km -o ./kbd.log &
```

it hogs the CPU usage to 50% and never logs a keystroke (in fact the 
kbd.log file is never created)

Any clues?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [logkeys](http://code.google.com/p/logkeys/) instead. It is newer and better than lkl, and should support your system as well.

Comment: logkeys works like a charm, thx